# Regex Matching State Statutes Formats

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am trying to parse State Statutes from court opinions.

In this case I am trying to match with West Virginia, which the citations will usually be in one of the following formats:

```
W. Va. Code Ann. § 24A-2-5(a)
W.Va. Code § 15A-5-3
W.Va.Code § 22B-3-1
W. Va. Code § 15A-5-3
West Virginia Code Ann § 53-4A-7(a)
```

I have already gotten this Regex string partially functional:

```
(W\.V\.|W\.Va\.|West\sVa\.|West\.Va\.|W\. Va\.|West\sVirginia|West\.Virginia)(/s?|.?)(Code\sAnn\.|Code|Code\sAnn?)(.\s?|\s?)(ȼs|&sect;|&#167|section|§|sect?)(\s+[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9a-zA-Z]+-[0-9])(\([a-z]\))?
```

The issue is that it does not match to the last format above: (West Virginia Code Ann § 53-4A-7(a))

I also know this is probably not the most efficient way to do this. So would the Regex Masters give me some pointers on what I am missing, and suggestions to improve it.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Not sure if regex is the best tool for what you're doing, but I think it's a viable approach. Are you keen on a 100% regex solution, or are you using a programming language as well? For example, it could be better to split the job between regex and string parsing rather than make a single overcomplicated regular expression.

Comment: Try `\b(?:W\.\s*Va\.|West\s+Virginia)\s*Code(?:\s+Ann\.?)?\s*§\s*\d+[A-Z]*-\d+[A-Z]*-\d+(?:\(\w+\))?`, see https://regex101.com/r/OlX72Y/1

Comment: Mike, your regex contains an incorrect slash and did not match the last example because your `[a-zA-Z]+` clause requires a letter following the "53" in your last example. Wiktor's solution is good.

Comment: Seth this is actually being used to search a database I built of court opinions so the regex is going in the Query for Postgres

Comment: Can you show some near misses? Edge cases of similar input but which should *not* match?

Comment: Did my solution from the comment work?

Answer (score 1):

Try this pattern

```
W(?:\. ?Va\.|est Virginia) ?Code(?: Ann\.?)? (?:§|ȼs|&#167|section|&sect;|sect\?) \d+[A-Z]?-\d+[A-Z]?-\d+(?:\([a-z]\))?
```

[image]

Where:

- `W(?:\. ?Va\.|est Virginia) ?` - Match the different formats of West Virginia
- `Code(?: Ann\.?)?`  - Match "Code" with the optional "Ann"
- `(?:§|ȼs|&#167|section|&sect;|sect\?)`  - Match the different formats of section keyword
- `\d+[A-Z]?-\d+[A-Z]?-\d+` - Match the section part e.g. `1a-2b-3`
- `(?:\([a-z]\))?` - Match an optional letter enclosed in parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

This is probably good enough:

```
(?:W\. *Va\.|West Virginia) ?Code.*(?:section|§|sect).*\w+(?:-\w+){2}(?:\(\w\))?
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/fUIWJRrdbYh6gC).